# Angular 2 Routing 3 level with empty component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem routing in angular 2

i need to route this url

```
mydomain/app/page/spk/crtspk
```

my folder path

```
-app
|  --page
|  |--spk
|  |  |--crtspk
|  |  |  |--crtspk.component
|  |  |  |--crtspk.data
|  |  |  |--crtspk.style
|  |  |  |--crtspk.template
|  |  |--spk.module
|  |--page.module
|  --layout
app.component
etc
```

i want to build app when access

```
mydomain/app/page = redirect to ->mydomain/app/page/spk/crtspk
```

and when access

```
mydomain/app/page/spk = redirect to ->mydomain/app/page/spk/crtspk
```

the problem is when i build that i got error "has no exported member 'SpkModule' on spk.module

i already try to redirect like this on page.module

```
export const routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'crtspk', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'crtspk', component: CrtSpk}
];
```

but the result path is

```
mydomain/app/page/crtspk
```

i want result path like this

```
mydomain/app/page/spk/crtspk
```

my spk.module route

```
import { CrtSpk} from './spk/crtspk/CrtSpk.component';
export const routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'crtspk', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'crtspk', component: CrtSpk}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CrtSpk,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  schemas:  [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export default class SpkModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

This is my page.module

```
import { SpkModule} from './spk/spk.module';


export const routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'spk', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'spk', component: SpkModule}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Autosize,
    OnlyNumber,
    SpkModule
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TooltipModule,
    AlertModule,
    DropdownModule,
    WidgetModule,
    NKDatetimeModule,
    Select2Module,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export default class PageModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

Hopefully someone help me to solve my problem

Comment: Can you post the routes in your spk.module

Comment: i've made change on my post

Comment: Shouldn't page routes be export const routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'spk', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

Comment: if i access mydomain/app/page/spk that should redirect into mydomain/app/page/spk/crtspk